# Bash: How to pass input file content as command argument

Tags: bash

I have a command `command` that takes an input file as argument. Is there a way to call `command` without actually creating a file?

I would like to achieve the following behavior

```
$ echo "content" > tempfile
$ command tempfile
$ rm tempfile
```

if possible:

- as a one-liner,
- without creating a file,
- using either a bash (or sh) feature or a "well-known" command (as standard as `xargs`)

It feels like there must be an easy way to do it but I can't find it.

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505828/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-command-that-expects-a-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

```
command <(echo "content")
```

Bash will create a FIFO or other type of temporary file in /dev for the standard output of whatever happens in the process. For example:

```
$ echo <(echo hi)
/dev/fd/63
```

Comment: Here string would be another option: `command <<< "content"`. Then, a pipe: `echo "content" | command`

Comment: @EugeniuRosca I think that misrepresents the original question. Presumably OP has a command that expects a file, not simply standard input. Although, many such commands will look in standard input if the file name is `-`.

Comment: You are right. If the OP's `command` expects a filename as argument and the `command` cannot be altered by OP to accept stdin, then my suggestions are wrong. Thanks for feedback.